# PHP http handling

Tags: php, http

Is there a way to prevent a php script from sending a http response when the script is finished executing? If not in php is it possible in any-other common web scripting langues?

Comment: ...just don't echo/return anything?

Comment: could you give more details of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: What would you want to happen instead? Let the browser hang there wasting one of its TCP/IP threads waiting for a response until the connection times out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that would be something controlled by the web server, not the scripting language.

Comment: Agreed. PHP just terminate the script. Then Apache replies back to the client to send "no data" in addition to a header 200 OK.

Answer (score 0):

assuming no headers have been sent, just 
die();

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can send a [http 204 (No Content)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).